# Angular databinding not updated after jQuery access child elements in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a full-screen loading splash that is shown over my app while the controllers initialize. The splash is triggered by a variable in the root scope which is toggled when everything completes. After adding a jQuery animation to elements inside the splash div, the ng-show directive no longer updates in Chrome, until a window event like a resize happens. Other browsers behave as expected.

I've tried printing the bound value inside the div, and sure enough it continues to show the old value even though the console logs show that it was changed. The jQuery code does not change any attributes of the splash div itself or access any scope variables, so I don't understand how it could block the directive from observing the root scope.

HTML

```
<div class="overlay" ng-show="showSplash">
  <div id="overlay__logo">{{showSplash}}</div>
  <div id="overlay__one" class="h1 overlay--text">some text</div>
  <div id="overlay__two" class="h1 overlay--text">some other text</div>
</div>
```

Angular utility called by various controllers

```
function showSplash() {
  $rootScope.showSplash = true;
  splashCounter += 1;
  console.log("Splash counter: " + splashCounter);
}

function hideSplash() {
  splashCounter -= 1;
  console.log("Splash counter: " + splashCounter);
  if (splashCounter < 1) {
    $rootScope.showSplash = false;
    $('.phone-screens').cycle();
    console.log("cleared splash");
  }
}
```

jQuery animation

```
function animateSplash() {
  // Increment splash counter again so it stays visible until this animation completes
  utility.showSplash();
  var dX = $('#overlay__two').width() / 2;
  $('#overlay__logo').animate({ left: '-=' + (dX + 140) }, function () {
    $('#overlay__one').fadeToggle(1000).fadeToggle(1000, function () {
      $('#overlay__two').fadeToggle(1000).delay(1000).fadeToggle(1000, function () {
        $('#overlay__logo').animate({ left: '+=' + (dX + 140) }, utility.hideSplash);
      });
    });
  });
```

Chrome console output:

```
utility.js:117 Splash counter: 1
utility.js:117 Splash counter: 2
utility.js:117 Splash counter: 3
utility.js:117 Splash counter: 4
utility.js:122 Splash counter: 3
utility.js:122 Splash counter: 2
utility.js:122 Splash counter: 1
utility.js:122 Splash counter: 0
utility.js:126 cleared splash
```

Comment: Here, angular scope is modified externally i.e) not within angular scope chain. So you need to inform angular that the scope is modified externally. Use `$rootScope.$applyAsync()` in both `showSplash()` and `hideSplash()` method. Hope this helps.

Comment: @ajaiJothi That does seem to solve it. I don't understand though how I'm modifying the scope externally since Angular and jQuery don't access any of the same properties. If you can explain a bit what's going on I'd accept that as answer.

Comment: AngularJS will account for only those model changes which are done inside AngularJS’ context. Angular’s built-in directives already do this so that any model changes you make are reflected in the view. However, if you change any model outside of the Angular context, then you need to inform Angular of the changes by calling `$apply()` or `$applyAsync()` manually. It’s like telling Angular that you are changing some models and it should fire the watchers so that your changes propagate properly.

Comment: Eg: if you use JavaScript’s setTimeout() function to update a scope model, Angular has no way of knowing what you might change. In this case it’s your responsibility to call `$apply()` manually, which triggers a `$digest` cycle.